# jdk for Mac and Parallels on mac

Tags: java

I have Windows installed on my Mac through Parallels.

I have to use eclipse for windows and also want to use IntelliJ on  Mac.

Do I need to have separate jdk installed for windows and MacOS, or just one(installed on Mac) will work for both?

Comment: Parallels doesn't care about Java. The JDK is not shared between Mac and Windows

Comment: okay, so I understood that I have to have jdk on both, plz confirm? Also I think I can keep 2 different versions jav in this case, right?

Comment: You need to install one on Windows and Mac, yes. Try to at least keep the major version the same. Don't install Java 7 in one and 8 or 9 in the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need separate java for windows in parallels and for macos

for macos distributive is .dmg, for parallels is .exe (or .msi)

in parallels every programs (and java) works in windows, so need java for windows